# How to loop through json object with specific key and value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looping through a json object with the structure below:

```
var my_products = {
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "Product 1",
            "id": 001,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 2",
            "id": 002,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 3",
            "id": 003,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 4",
            "id": 004,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        }
    ]
};
```

I can loop through the object with the code below:

```
for(var i=0; i<my_products.products.length; i++) {
    var product = my_products.products[i];
    console.log(product);
    console.log('in_stock:',product.in_stock);
}
```

Do you know how can I loop through each record where Products that have a `"stock_quantity": 1 and "in_stock": true` properties?

In the example above there are 2 product records that have a "`stock_quantity": 1` property(not zero quantity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply you can iterate and `filter` data with `if` condition.

```js
var my_products = {
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "Product 1",
            "id": 001,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 2",
            "id": 002,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 3",
            "id": 003,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 4",
            "id": 004,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        }
    ]
};
var filterData = [];
$.each(my_products.products, function(){
    if (this.in_stock && this.stock_quantity === 1) {
        filterData.push(this);
    }
});
console.log(filterData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can `filter` the array first:

```js
var my_products = {
    "products": [
        {
            "title": "Product 1",
            "id": 001,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 2",
            "id": 002,
            "stock_quantity": 0,
            "in_stock": false
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 3",
            "id": 003,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        },
        {
            "title": "Product 4",
            "id": 004,
            "stock_quantity": 1,
            "in_stock": true
        }
    ]
};
console.log(
  my_products.products.filter(({ stock_quantity, in_stock }) => (
    in_stock && stock_quantity === 1
  ))
);
```